# Have Fomantic-UI (Angular-JS) sidebar scoll indipendantly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, fomantic-ui

Is there a method to get a sidebar to scroll indipendently from the content it pushes?

Right now I have a page set up in this fasion:

```
--------------------------
|[button]  Header        |
--------------------------
|S | Main content        |
|i |                     |
|d |                     |
|e |                     |
|b |                     |
|a |                     |
|r |                     |
--------------------------
| Footer                 |
--------------------------
```

The button I have in the header toggles the sidebar and when it's visible it will scroll along with the Main Content of the page.  I would like to keep this from happening, so if anyone can tell what I have to do it would be appreciated.

Below is the basic structure of my HTML (I can't post acttual code so please forgive me)

```html
<div class="ui segment pushable" style="margin-top:3.5em;" id="mainContent">
   <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical sidebar menu" id="individual_messages_sidebar">
      <!-- side bar content here -->
   </div>
   <div class="pusher">
      <!-- Main Content -->
   </div>
</div>
```

The code that initializes the sidebar in Javascript

```js
$('#individual_messages_sidebar')
   .sidebar({
      context: $('#mainContent')
   })
   .sidebar('setting', 'dimPage', false);
```

I've tried making the side bar and/or the main content sticky. Tried giving them fixed positions with CSS. Maybe some other things that I can't remmember, but nothing has really worked as I had hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) is what determines if you will have scroll bars.
you need a container that has a known height and inside you can have an element that has massive height and use overflow to control it.  [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mrf96yzx/)

```
.slider {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
.slider>div {
  background: #cddccd;
  width:130px;
  height:1000px;
}
.content {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  width:100%;
}
.content>div {
  background: #dccddc;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. At least it did if I just used the CSS for the slider.  Adding the content version stopped it working all together.